# Pattern Matching mingw make

Tags: c++, build, makefile

I'm extremely new to Makefiles, and I'm currently trying to build my first one on a project I'm starting.

The problem I'm having is having it automatically know how to handle all my .cpp files without defining rules for each one.

I also want my object files to all be put in one folder which is `$(PLATFORM)/obj`/ where `PLATFORM=win32` in this case.

The follwing is what I'm using for a Makefile, executing it with mingw32-make.exe

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -Wall -DALLEGRO_STATICLINK
LDFLAGS=
PLATFORM=win32
SOURCES=main.cpp
EXECUTABLE=app.exe
OBJDIR=$(PLATFORM)/obj/
OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)%.o)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)  $< -o $@


$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I'm getting the error:

> mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target `win32/obj/main.o', needed by`
>   app.exe' .  Stop.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've been looking around at other examples of makefiles and they seem to have a similar structure, so I'm not sure whats wrong with mine. I'm looking for an explanation of why this is happening, and advice on how to fix it.
Also, any comments on my style, suggestions for making it more clean/standardized would be great as well. While learning to make makefiles, I want to make sure I'm learning properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` sees that it needs to create `win32/obj/main.o`, but can't see any rule to tell it how to do that.

You have three rules, one for `all`, one for `%.o` and one for `$(EXECUTABLE)`. The first one and the last one will not tell `make` how to create `win32/obj/main.o`.

The second rule probably should, but it says this: if you want to create `<something>.o`, then first make sure that there's a file called `<something>.c` (if it doesn't exist, try to find a rule to make it). Then run the following command: `$(CXX) ...`

But the file `<something>.c` doesn't exist, because your files end with `.cpp`. So this rule fails. `make` can't find any other rule to build `win32/obj/main.o`, so it gives up.

In summary, you need to change the rule so that `%.o` depends on `%.cpp`, and then `make` will be able to run the command to create the object file. So the rule should be:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)  $< -o $@
```

By the way, `make` also has predefined implicit rules. Because you give an explicit rule for `%.o` you're actually overriding the predefined rule. I suggest you try at some point not to give this rule at all (but still define `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`) and see what happens. See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) for details.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I got it working by changing %.0: %.cpp to $(OBJDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.cpp. Thanks, I understand how it works a little more now

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to dissuade you from using manual makefiles, but if you want to eliminate the problem altogether, there are autotools available that will generate the makefiles for you. Since you're using Windows, I suspect you're using cygwin (or perhaps MingGW). For cygwin, just download the autotools binary package. If you're using eclipse for your IDE (which I strongly promote), you can configure your environment to pick up on the autotools. This way, you just focus on writing the code. All configurability options still exist, but you don't have to know make.